# How to grab attribute from button?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get an alert of this button's data, specifically the '6374' part. Any ideas how to grab it with jQuery?

html:

```
<button data-snax-post="6374">Text</button>
```

jquery:

```
alert(('.menu-item').attr('data-snax-post'));
```

Comment: You are just missing `$` for jQuery sign in your alert. Add that it will work fine. Also, use this `alert($('button').attr('data-snax-post'));` since you do NOT have any class at current or add class `.menu-item` to your button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button needs to have the `menu-item` class so you can select it that way.

You left out `$` to call the jQuery function to select the item.

You can use the `.data()` method to get data attributes.

```js
alert($('.menu-item').data('snax-post'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="menu-item" data-snax-post="6374">Text</button>
```

But this won't work if there's more than one `.menu-item` element on your page. It will get the data from the first one. If you're clicking on it, you probably want to use `$(this)`.

```js
$(".menu-item").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).data('snax-post'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="menu-item" data-snax-post="6374">Text</button>
<button class="menu-item" data-snax-post="1234">Other Text</button>
```

Comment: Is not that considered a typo only question ? Just wondering since OP is only missing `$` The rest is all fine will work  100%.

Comment: They were also missing the class in the element.

Comment: or you can do `alert($('button').attr('data-snax-post'));` Just based on the question !

Comment: There's likely to be more than one button.

Answer (score 1):

```
you were missing $ and you don't have menu-item class in button element 

<button data-snax-post="6374">Text</button>

 alert($('button').attr('data-snax-post'));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I said in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `alert($('.menu-item').data('snax-post'));` to alert the data-snax-post attribute

Comment: That's not the problem.